# Using fpdf to modify existing pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a bank of pdfs on my server which when downloaded need text appended to every page. I am using fpdf to try and open the file, append the text to each page, close the file and serve to the browser.

```
$pdf = new FPDI();

$pdf->setSourceFile($filename); 
// import page 1 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
//use the imported page and place it at point 0,0; calculate width and height
//automaticallay and ajust the page size to the size of the imported page 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true); 

// now write some text above the imported page 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', '13'); 
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
//set position in pdf document
$pdf->SetXY(20, 20);
//first parameter defines the line height
$pdf->Write(0, 'gift code');
//force the browser to download the output
$pdf->Output('gift_coupon_generated.pdf', 'D');

header("location: ".$filename);
```

At the minute this just tries to put some text anywhere on the pdf and save it but I get the error

```
FPDF error: You have to add a page first!
```

If I can get it to do this I then need it to append the text to every page in the document rather than just 1, not sure how to do this having read the documentation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try following

```
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf =& new FPDI();
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Use this page as template, then

```
$pdf->setSourceFile($filename); 
// import page 1 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
//use the imported page and place it at point 0,0; calculate width and height
//automaticallay and ajust the page size to the size of the imported page 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);
```

Let me know if you have any errors

Comment: worked for me only using Nulls in $x & $y
`$outPdf->useTemplate($outPdf->importPage($i), null, null, 0, 0, true);`. Otherwise It cuts Pages to A4.

Answer (score 11):

Since you want all the pages with the text, one way to do it is putting the code in a loop.

Like this:

```
// Get total of the pages
$pages_count = $pdf->setSourceFile('your_file.pdf'); 

for($i = 1; $i <= $pages_count; $i++)
{
    $pdf->AddPage(); 

    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);

    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0); 


    $pdf->SetFont('Arial'); 
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0); 
    $pdf->SetXY(25, 25); 
    $pdf->Write(0, "This is just a simple text"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dhek graphical tool to design a template in JSON format, defining areas (bounds, name, ...) you want to add later on existing PDF (using FPDF and dynamic data). See doc at https://github.com/cchantep/dhek/blob/master/README.md#php-integration .